# How to stop all functions (multiple asyncs etc) from executing if user abort connecting to the server (refresh while connecting, close browser, etc..)

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, express, reactjs

I'm currently working with React.js and Server-Side rendering where I have multiple async calls requesting json from API server. So the problem is if user stops connecting, the functions keep executing even though it has nobody to serve it to.

For example if I hold down refresh button, the node.js Express server will keep sending hundreds of async requests (and probably non async functions as well which take longer to execute) and then executing functions once received response.

So basically I need some way to stop functions from firing if user stops HTTP request, worst case if holding refresh button down...

I've tried to use res.end(), but the functions keep firing. Is there some smart way to listen to an event and stop the async or something?

requests are made with "superagent" and async with "async.js"

Thanks.

Comment: Where is it that you decide you want to abort open connections?  On the server?  Or in the browser?  And, are you only trying to abort existing connections or any other connections that might be about to happen from the same client?

Comment: How it works for me now: 1) User(browser) -> 2) Server HTTP request -> 3) Functions such as Async start requesting api from api server -> 4) Before completing, user refreshes browser, press esc... etc -> 5) Server keeps firing functions

Comment: So, you're trying to accomplish what exactly?  When the page is refreshed, the browser will drop all currently open connections and those responses will not be processed by the browser.  The server may not instantly see that the connections have been dropped, but it will notice fairly soon (perhaps when sending the response).  So, what is it that you're trying to change?

Comment: Stop the server firing the functions that should only happen if the user stays connected. Because right now if the user drops the connection, all the functions keep firing...  Does this make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no particularly great options for you on the server.

If a single client sends off multiple requests from the server and then while the requests are being processed or are in the server queue waiting to be processed, the end user hits refresh, then the browser will drop/close the open Ajax sockets that the currently open web page has.

But, requests that are already underway on the server will continue to process and the server will not even know that those sockets have been closed until the server tries to write to those sockets.  At that point, it may (depending upon timing) discover that the sockets have been closed.  But, of course by that time, you've already processed the requests and have the results ready to go.  It may also occur that the request is processed and sent before the server is even aware that the sockets have been closed.  This will eventually cause an error on the socket (and a resulting close of the socket) when no response comes back from the other end or a close comes back from the other end while awaiting confirmation of the data that was sent (since TCP is a reliable protocol, every send must be ACKed by the other end of the connection).

So, this all explains why there really isn't a whole lot you can do on the server.

---

The situation you describe will be exacerbated if the client is sending multiple API requests in parallel and the end-user is somehow led to refresh the page in the middle of that.  The things you can do to lessen this issue are as follows:

1. Combine multiple requests into a single API request.  If your API already permits that type of structuring of the request, then switch to that.  Or, if you control the API, then add new capabilities to the API so that rather than having a client send multiple requests in parallel, it can send a single request and get all the data in that one request.  This limits the number of requests that might get caught in process when the web page is closed.
2. Limit the number of parallel requests you send.  You can do this either by using the Async library feature that controls how many requests are sent at once from a list of requests you're trying to send or you can serialize your requests so one is sent only after the previous one finishes.  This would also limit the number of requests that might get caught in process when the web page is closed.
3. If you had a particularly expensive server-side operation (something that might take minutes to run such as building a large report file), you could devise some sort of check-in with the client and then during your processing you could check to see if the  client was still active and if not, then you could abort your own server-side processing.  For most normal types of server-side requests, this would probably not be worth the extra trouble (since verifying the client is still active has its own cost), but if you have a particularly costly server-side operation, you could implement something like this.
4. If you have async operations in your request processing and if you're willing to put checks into your request handling after each async operation, then you could register a listener for the `'close'` with `req.connection.addListener('close', function () { ... });`, then set some sort of flag on that request that you check after each async operation and then abort the rest of the request processing whenever you discover that flag on that connection.  I scoured the `net` module docs for some flag or method on the socket object that would tell you if it's already been closed (such information should be there), but I could not find it mentioned in the nodejs doc.

Comment: There is a way to check server side if connection closed: req.connection.addListener('close', function () {}); I was hoping perhaps there's some clever way of taking advantage of this that I can't figure out by myself right now.. It seems to work quite fine and quickly recognizes if user drops connection. Did you take this into account?

Comment: @Martastico - In a single threaded environment, that's not particularly  simple to use because events are queued in roughly the order they occur so you'd have to find a way to both get that close event in time and then abort your own processing.  Remember, if you're in the middle of processing some request, no other events will get processed until you're done (at which point you're already done with the request).  It would take a bunch of experimentation to figure out if you could actually receive that event in time to help you.

Comment: @Martastico - If you have a bunch of async operations in your request process and you're willing to check some flag on your connection after every async operation (to then abort the processing of the request), you might be able to see some savings.  If you don't have async operations, then the event won't occur while you're processing the request.

Comment: Ah interesting, thanks for thoroughly explaining how it works. The reason I brought up this problem is that when I keep refreshing in browser, the server seems to "stop" and clog up with Async Requests, and I can't receive anything from the server for some time. The first Async HTTP requests I have will get all the initial JSON data, next it renders the app. With connection('close') I'm able to stop most functions from firing while getting data because I'm able to send callback to Async preventing rendering the app after async requests are done.

Comment: @Martastico - We'd have to see the relevant client and server code and understand how your multiple requests work to really be able to comment further on how useful the close event could be really as it depends on how your code works.  I will add a mention of it to my answer as it is definitely another option to use.

Comment: Hopefully this code is sufficient enough to understand: https://jsfiddle.net/nfgtscrt/ Server uses Async called "Actions.routeLoad". Inside "routeLoad", it has the requests Async requesting the initial json data in parallel. Once all data received, it sends an event to "routeLoadingDone", where it sends "success" callback to "Actions.routeLoad.completed(true)", then in the server section it will continue with the res.render. "Actions" is basically just an event, part of "Reflux.js". I hope that's clear enough.

Comment: The whole source is here: https://github.com/Martastico/personal-portfolio But I think that's too much to dig through.

Answer (score 0):

Aborting requests halfway through isn't the job of `async`. From `async`'s point of view, a request to the server is just a single task that can't be split up any further. If it is possible to do something like this, it would be part of the built-in `http` module or `express`. But I'm not sure that it would be very helpful, even if there is a way of doing it. The request has probably reached the internet by the time you try to unsend it. What you really want is not to send so many requests in the first place.

You haven't posted any code, so I can't write modifications to your code in response. Instead of having an event handler that says "send a request and do something with the response", write one that says "if you haven't sent a request in the last 2 seconds, send one and do something with the response, and also save the response in a variable; otherwise, look at the value of the variable and pretend you've received it as the response". (I'm assuming that all requests are identical - if not, then you need to think a bit more about it.)

Comment: Well it doesn't matter what my code is, the problem is that once the HTTP request by the user from browser to server has been made, I can't stop functions from firing once the user has stopped the request, such as refresing the browser, pressing esc... etc. I'm trying to find a good solution to control how to stop the functions from firing if this happens?